# how to split for each result into 2 different results design?

Tags: php, foreach

I made this code for a plugin but it will put all the results under each others which i don't want, I want to split them in 2 different results so i can put every 2 in one line.

```
        <?php
            $courses = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT odoo_id,name FROM wp_course");
            foreach ($courses as $cours){
                $registers = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_registers where course_id = " . $cours->odoo_id );
                if(count($registers)>0){
                    echo '<p class="onabold">'.$cours->name.'</p>';
                    echo '<select name="course321[]" class="select-field">';
                    echo '<option value=""></option>';
                    foreach ($registers as $reg){
                        echo '<option value="'.$reg->odoo_id.'">'.$reg->name.' - price '.$reg->price.'</option>';
                    }
                    echo '</select>';
                }
            }
        ?>
```

anyone can tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

put select inside paragraph

```
if(count($registers)>0){
                    echo '<p class="onabold">'.$cours->name;
                    echo '<select name="course321[]" class="select-field">';
                    echo '<option value=""></option>';
                    foreach ($registers as $reg){
                        echo '<option value="'.$reg->odoo_id.'">'.$reg->name.' - price '.$reg->price.'</option>';
                    }
                    echo '</select></p>';
                }
```